# Setting new value into field created by PyQGIS?

Tags: pyqgis, fields-attributes, expression

I'd like to create a new field named "vctcn93", loop the features of active layer, if string "metro" in feature name, I'd like to add a value string "get" into the field "vctcn93".

But when I check the table, I found a field named "vctcn93" but null value in it.

[image]

When I check some features in console, the features got the value already.

[image]

These are my codes first time:

```
 def AddAttri():
    layer = qgis.utils.iface.activeLayer()
    pr = layer.dataProvider()
    feild = QgsField("vctcn93", QVariant.String, "text", 254)
    pr.addAttributes([feild])
    layer.updateFields()

    layer.selectAll()
    ids = layer.selectedFeatureIds()
    features = (f for f in layer.getSelectedFeatures())

    index = a.fieldNameIndex("vctcn93")

    for a in features:
        if "metro_station" in a.attribute("name"):
            a.setAttribute(index, "get")

    layer.updateFeature(a)
```

And I tried another way to figure it out, but failed.

Field with blank value in the table the same.

Codes second time.

```
def AddAttri():
    layer = qgis.utils.iface.activeLayer()
    pr = layer.dataProvider()
    feild = QgsField("vctcn93", QVariant.String, "text", 254)
    pr.addAttributes([feild])
    layer.updateFields()

    layer.selectAll()
    ids = layer.selectedFeatureIds()
    features = (f for f in layer.getSelectedFeatures())

    index = a.fieldNameIndex("vctcn93")

    for a in features:
        if "metro_station" in a.attribute("name"):
            fs = a.fields()
            fs.append(feild)
            a.setFields(fs)
            a.setAttribute(index, text)

    layer.updateFeature(a)
```

Answer (score 1):

Modify

```
for a in features:
    if "metro_station" in a.attribute("name"):
        fs = a.fields()
        fs.append(feild)
        a.setFields(fs)
        a.setAttribute(index, text)

layer.updateFeature(a)
```

To

```
for a in features:
    if "metro_station" in a.attribute("name"):
        fs = a.fields()
        fs.append(feild)
        a.setFields(fs)
        a.setAttribute(index, text)
        layer.updateFeature(a)
```

This way you update every feature in the layer that satisfied your if statement and not just the last feature in features.